# Change GET-URL to canonical (mod_rewrite)

Tags: forms, url, mod-rewrite

For my search engine, I have the page ...

/index.php?q=TERM

... which displays the search results.

Using mod_rewrite, I made it accessible via:

/q/TERM

The rule I used in the .htaccess was something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^q/(.+)$ index.php?q=$1
```

This works well. But when I enter a term into my HTML form and click the submit button, I'm still redirected to ...

/index.php?q=TERM

How can I make my GET-form directly calling the new and short URL? Its code is:

```
<form action="/index.php" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
...
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A from will always call your page with `?q=TERM` and your rewrite rule only say : `/q/TERM` is in fact `?q=TERM`

Then you need to rewrite `?q=TERM` to `/q/TERM first`. But we need to take care of loops.

So let's try :

EDIT1: other flags. (I found that [C] re run the rules, so we don't want that)

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /q/%1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^q/(.+)$ index.php?q=$1 [NC,L]
```

Tell me how that behave.

Related: [SO entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466166/redirect-and-rewrite-with-mod-rewrite/5472200#5472200)

Comment: Thank you for this answer :) Unfortunately, my browser tells me: The website redirects this request so that it can never be finished. So the first two lines (RewriteCond + RewriteRule) don't work. The last lines works as it is the line I had before as well.

Comment: Hum, I bet it would fail but can't test it. Gonna check another thread where there was a similar loop.

Comment: Now I get this error message: "Internal Server Error: The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request."

Comment: You have access or error logs to help debug? EDIT: set it up on my config : redirect loop. fixing.

Comment: You simply made a mistake while copying the code from your answer to the other question ;) It works perfectly with the second line being: RewriteRule ^$ /q/%1? [NC,R,L]

Comment: Oh nice, did not catch that! good job. I'll edit to make it match the correct anwser.