# Generating clean URLs when using forms

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is the form:

```
<form action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>'>
  <p><label>Movie Title:</label><input type='text' name='search'></p>
  <p><input id="submit" type='submit' value='Submit'></p>
</form>
```

When the form is submitted, currently the URL returns like so:

```
localhost/movie/index.php?search=ted
```

I would like for the URL to return like so:

```
localhost/movie/search/ted
```

EDIT:

I now have the following code in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^search=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /search/%1 [NC,R,L] 
RewriteRule ^search/(.+)$ index.php?search=$1 [NC,L]
```

This works when you type in the URL `/movie/search/ted` but when you submit the form it still comes out as `/movie/index.php?search=ted`

Comment: this code is vulnerable to xss.

Comment: How so? Would be nice to build on your comment!

Comment: `http://localhost/movie/index.php/'><script>alert(/xss/)</script>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rewrite rules don't change the url, they just tell your server to interpret url that falls under the rule `^search/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$` like `index.php?search=$1`.

If you want to change the link that will be used, you have to change it in your html `<form action=''`

Comment: How would I go about doing that, as I have tested a lot of possibilities and still not got the desired result.

Comment: this answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464481/clean-urls-for-search-query) should help you with that

Comment: The only URL I can seem to get is: `localhost/movie/search/?search=ted` everything else I have tried either seems to cause a redirect loop or just fails completely.