# remove query string form url with htaccess

Tags: php, string, .htaccess, url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Clean URLs for search query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464481/clean-urls-for-search-query)

I made a php webpage for checking the color code,here is the first four line

```
if(isset($_GET['c']))
$hex = $_GET['c'];
elseif(!isset($_GET['c']))
$hex = $_POST['c'];
```

and my htaccess have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]{6})$ index.php?c=$1 [L]
```

if I type site.com/ffcdee it successfully show the color #ffcdee
but if i use the input box:

```
<form action="">
<input type="text" name="c" >
<input type="submit" value="Search" id="search-submit">
</form>
```

it show site.com/?c=ffcdee,
I tried change input name to other word,but the script not work anymore..
how can I remove the ?c= from the url?

Comment: With a redirect, or updating the request URL per Javascript.

Comment: one more problem:If I use the input box enter three digits color hex code it can show up the color(/?c=F00),but if I enter three digits color hex code in url(/F00) it not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the http post method instead of http get:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="c" >
<input type="submit" value="Search" id="search-submit">
</form>
```

When using http post requests the query arguments are not passed coded inside the url, instead they are handed over as a separate "body" of the request. The content of that body is what you finally get presented inside php as the $_POST superglobal variable.

If you want to understand how that works use a network sniffer like `wireshark` to dump the http traffic. You will see and understand the difference between get and post.