# htaccess: redirect urls with actions from GET?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

First of all let me say: I have almost no experience with htaccess and all code looks like gibberish to me.

I have a form that send the visitor to a page like this:
mysite.com/date.php?day=2014-06-03

I want them automatically redirected to:
mysite.com/2014-06-03

I currently have the following code in my htaccess, which already makes the page work, the old page just does not get redirected yet.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* date.php/?day=$0 [PT]
```

I'd be really glad if someone could take a look at this. It seems like this should be fairly easy but all the similar questions are JUST a bit different or too hard for me.

EDIT:

Changed my form using this question:
[Clean URLs for search query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464481/clean-urls-for-search-query)

Comment: Solved it using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464481/clean-urls-for-search-query .

Answer (score 0):

The RewriteRule directive doesn't operate on the query string. It only works with paths. 
You need to add a condition on the query string:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^day=([^&]+)
RewriteRule $/date.php^ /date.php/?day=%1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I tried the code above but it doesn't really do anything.. It still goes to the full URL, not the 'cleaner' one..

Comment: Still nothing. Just to clarify, do I need to remove anything from my original code?