# Laravel form method get - url parameters

Tags: php, forms, url, laravel, get

I got a form in laravel with `Method='GET'`

```
{{ Form::open(array('method' => 'get')) }}
```

I got a few input fields in there: `city, skillLevel, province and category`.
When i submit the form i get a awfull url like this:

```
http://localhost/vacatures?city=somehwhere&skillLevel=junior&province=Zeeland&category=django
```

but i want something like this:

```
http://localhost/vacatures/somewhere/junior/Zeeland/django
```

How do i achieve this? I've tried giving at a route attribute and a action actribute, but that didnt work out.

Comment: I am afraid that is how html works. You can look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464481/clean-urls-for-search-query and http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/how-to-post-forms-to-clean-rewritten-urls They are both basically hacks so I am guessing there is no standard way to go about this.

Comment: Well, if i would to stick with the ugly url, how can i use a Route that catches this?

Comment: Wouldn't it be available to the vacatures controller by default ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this topic will help you - [How To Pass GET Parameters To Laravel From With GET Method ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27298426/how-to-pass-get-parameters-to-laravel-from-with-get-method)

There are 2 nice answers, which should suit to your problem.

Comment: Thanks! Did not come across this answer yet!