# Adding parameters in form action when submit

Tags: php, html

How can I add may parameters when submitting my form.

```
<form name="frmSearch" action="list-of-all-jobs/by-date" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="kewords" id="keywords">
</form>
```

I already Rewrite my url to list-of-all-jobs/by-date. I just want to add may keywords parameter in the action when submitting so that the link of the page must be site.com/list-of-all-jobs/by-date/keywords.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clean URLs for search query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464481/clean-urls-for-search-query)

Answer (score 0):

**Post action** - Appends form-data inside the body of the HTTP request.
The request parameters are added in the URL seperated by '&'.
In your case it will be 
`list-of-all-jobs/by-date?keywords=keys`.
If you want to add many keys either provide many input fields or append the keys using using commas like

```
list-of-all-jobs/by-date?keywords=key1,key2`
```

And do the processing in the server by splitting the query string parameter by commas.

Answer (score -1):

You can change the form action using jquery.

**HTMl is:**

```
<form name="frmSearch" action="list-of-all-jobs/by-date" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="kewords" id="keywords"/>
    <input type="submit" id="submitaction"/>
</form>
```

**Jquery is:**

```
$('#submitaction').click(function(e)
{
    $("form").attr('action', 'list-of-all-jobs/by-date?keywords='+$('#keywords').val());
});
```